# Flutter File Access to external Storage

Tags: flutter, permissions, storage, external

In my Flutter-App I want to read data from a text-File, that I have created on my Computer and uploaded to my Mobile. But I'm not able to open this File for reading data, I always get a permission denied. First the Code, where I tried to read:

```
void importieren()async{
    if (await Permission.storage.request().isGranted) {
      String extPath = await ExternalPath.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
          ExternalPath.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
      File importFile = await File(extPath + '/rezept/' + _importFile);
      List<String> lines = await importFile.readAsLines();
      lines.forEach((String line) {
        List<String> zeile = line.split('\t');
        Rezept rezept = Rezept.fromList(zeile);
        myDB.addRezept(rezept);
      });
    }
  }
```

In the Manifest.xml I have integrated:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <application
       android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

Creating and Writing to Files in this Directory is no problem, but whenever I want access an existing file - I'm not allowed. I've tried it with different Directories, but I didn't find one, that works.